# Performance of loading fields

Tags: php, performance, object-oriented, php5

I wrote a class with this function. Can I improve my code performance in the bottom of the function? I don't like the `while` loops!

```
public function loadFields(array $fields, $as_object = Config::FIELDS_AS_OBJECT) {
        $connection = $this->connection;
        $sql = "SELECT ".implode(",", $fields)." FROM ".$this->table." WHERE lang = ?";
        if (!($stmt = $connection->prepare($sql))){
            throw new MysqliPrepareException($connection);
        }
        if(!($stmt->bind_param('s',$this->lang))){
            throw new MysqliBindParamException($connection);
        }
        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            throw new MysqliExecuteException($connection);
        }
        $stmt->store_result();
        $variables = array();
        $data = array();
        $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
            $variables[] = &$data[$field->name];
        }
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $variables);
        $i = 0;
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $array[$i] = array();
            foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
                $array[$i][$k] = $v;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $array = (!isset($array[1]) ? $array[0] : $array);
        return ($as_object == true ? (object) $array : $array);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd imagine a [`$stmt->fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) would be more performant than the while-loop and `$stmt->fetch()`. Rather than paging over an entire set of records one at a time, try returning the results from the database in-bulk. Your code is making a trip to the database with each iteration of your while loop. Your code will still look virtually identical:

```
$i = 0;
$r = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($r as $data) {
    $array[$i] = array();
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $array[$i][$k] = $v;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

If you're using mysqli (native driver only), and not PDO's MySQL, you could do this:

```
$i = 0;
$r = $stmt->get_result();
$r = $r->fetchAll();
foreach ($r as $data) {
    $array[$i] = array();
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $array[$i][$k] = $v;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

You shouldn't worry about loops per se, but performance hits that you see, whether they come from loops or not. This is only possible if you're profiling your code.

Comment: Yep, thanks, but this doesn't work for be because I use mysqli and the mysqli_stmt object doesn't have a method fetchAll.

Comment: Sorry user1232375, I didn't realize you're using mysqli. I added some code that should work as long as you're using a native mysqli driver. It uses the mysqli_stmt::get_result() method: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: Yep, tested it with mysql and it worked! Thank you for your work.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help! Would you mind accepting my answer?